# After installing Windows what should I do first? update or install antivirus?

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus

Normally, after reformating and installing Windows 7, I used to go online and install all the updates, install all the driver updates and then install the anti virus. Because long ago, when I installed the anti virus first, applying windows updates crashed the AV! So, I install it last. Specially 7 sp1 is critical right?

But now im having doubts... Going online without an antivirus means I'm vulnerable! (I have a home router which have a small firewall but I'm not sure about it) So, whats the best thing to do? Install the anti virus first or install the updates first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Antivirus hype is greatly exaggerated. You're not in any danger from viruses unless you install 3rd party software that may contain viruses, or visit web sites with malware using a vulnerable web browser. So, my suggestion would be:

1. Make sure you have a working firewall. Default Windows 7 firewall is fine.
2. Do **not** install anything, do not put any media (CDs, flash drives, etc.) into your computer. Do **not** browse the Internet!
3. Apply all pending updates, reboot as necessary (you will likely need to reboot many times to apply all updates on a freshly-installed Windows)
4. Install antivirus.

You mentioned reformatting, so I suppose your hard disk if completely empty. If you didn't reformat your hard disk completely, some viruses that you might had previously may be carried over into your new installation, so beware.

Comment: Yep.. its a full format :) Sometimes I even do a full lowelevel format. If not, simply create a new partition table and then crate the partitions separately. I even disconnect all the machines in the network before the upgdate... So, now im sure.. thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

When I update, my antivirus is running, with no problems. I use Microsoft Security Essentials as my first line of defence.

Answer (score 0):

Install antivirus and firewall then go online for the Windows Updates. Ars Technica recently wrote a nice [article](http://arstechnica.com/features/2012/06/blowing-away-bloatware-a-guide-to-reinstalling-windows-on-a-new-pc/) on re-installing Windows. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I Install all updates using Windows Updates first, then install AV, but that is just how I do it.

Yes SP1 is important. Windows Updates uses its own background protocol to install updates safely, so as long as you don't install any other software or use a Browser, you will be safe until you get updates and then AV on there.